# Not able to compile apache2.4.17 with mod_fastcgi

Tags: c, linux, apache, fastcgi, apache2.4

I am trying to compile apache 2.4.17 with FastCGI , i googled various tutorials and most of tutorials contained an command to include and patch from the following link https://github.com/ByteInternet/libapache-mod-fastcgi .

So instead of including their patch i downloaded their fork of FASTCGI and tried to compile against it and i am getting the following error

```
mod_fastcgi.c:2848: warning: passing argument 5 of 'ap_log_rerror_' makes integer from pointer without a
mod_fastcgi.c:2848: warning: passing argument 6 of 'ap_log_rerror_' from incompatible pointer type
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: warning: passing argument 5 of 'ap_log_rerror_' makes integer from pointer without a
mod_fastcgi.c:2863: warning: passing argument 6 of 'ap_log_rerror_' from incompatible pointer type
mod_fastcgi.c: In function 'check_access':
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: warning: passing argument 5 of 'ap_log_rerror_' makes integer from pointer without a
mod_fastcgi.c:2909: warning: passing argument 6 of 'ap_log_rerror_' from incompatible pointer type
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'log' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'connection' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: error: request for member 'server' in something not a structure or union
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: warning: passing argument 5 of 'ap_log_rerror_' makes integer from pointer without a
mod_fastcgi.c:2923: warning: passing argument 6 of 'ap_log_rerror_' from incompatible pointer type
```

I have googled this error and its an conversion error of pointer to struct
but i am not able to figure out what to change in the mod_fastcgi.c file

I am running Centos 5.8

This is the batch script code i am using to compile

```
tar -zxf mod_fastcgi.tar.gz
cd mod_fastcgi
cp Makefile.AP2 Makefile
echo $MAIN_SRC/$APACHE2
make top_dir=$MAIN_SRC/$APACHE2 
make install top_dir=$MAIN_SRC/$APACHE2
```

can any one help me debug this as i am trying from many hours still with no success . I also tried to compile with the default tar from fastcgi.com still got the same errors

Comment: all your errors are coming from ap_log_rerror(, try to comment it out first and then try to compile..as your first step..before that..try to run..make clean..

Comment: tried to comment it out but still no success

Comment: please give details of APACHE2 and MAIN_SRC, how did you install it, as I can only help you to debug it if I have complete details..in general..I do not use anything above..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the mod_fastcgi which is available from http://fastcgi.com , i compiled using the mod_fcgid which is available from apache .

Here is the link https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi .

Here is the commands i used :

```
tar -zxf mod_fcgid.tar.gz
cd mod_fcgid
APXS = path/to/apxs ./configure.apxs
```